# How can I change directory into any a folder two directories below without specifying parent directories?

Tags: linux

Im creating a script that will help automate the updating of git repositories from their remote sources.
Right now the script looks like this:

```
for i in $(/bin/ls */*/ -1 | grep /: -v)
do
    echo "==> Fetching $i"
    cd */*/$i
    git remote update
    cd ../../..
done
```

The only problem I'm having trouble with is the

```
cd */*/$i
```

part

How would I be able to cd into these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$i` already has the directory as part of it, so you don't need the asterisks with `cd`.

Also, you can use `ls -d` so you don't need to grep.

Also, you could wrap the commands from `cd` to `git` in one set of parenthesis `( ... )` so you don't need `cd -`.

Comment: Note that if you don't use `-d`, you'll have to get rid of the trailing `:` char somehow.   You could uses `sed` instead of `grep`:   `/bin/ls */*/ |sed -n 's|/:$||p'`

Answer (score 0):

If they all will have a `.git` directory...

Something like

```
for i in $(find /path/to/top -name .git -type d -exec dirname {} \;)
do
  cd $i
  echo Updating in $PWD
  git remote update
  cd -
done
```

may work for you...

Comment: That only gives me the first result rather than all

Comment: @Akuhcap - Hrm. I tested by pointing it to my `~/NetbeansProjects` folder, which contains about 20 different git repos, and it echoed out appropriate information for each (I didn't actually run a `git remote update`, rest of the script I posted ran as-is).  None of my git projects contain other git projects though.   Perhaps post a sample `tree` output of your directory structure?

Comment: Its quite a big directory, as it is a lot of software i keep so that I can compile when needed, but the scheme is like this 

/mnt/archive/source-code/git/SERVICE/USER/REPO

Service meaning github.com or gitlab.com, user being the user, and repo being the repo

Comment: I tested the `find` command in the solution by @ivanivan and it returned all my directories containing .git, so it should work.